# insert images in noweb html

Tags: graphics

I tried to insert an image into the noweb source file. Something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cases}
    \caption{Different cases}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

It works when I tried to generate the pdf file using the command:

```
noweave -delay -n -index src.nw > src.tex
pdflatex src.tex
```

However, when I tried to generate the html file using the following command, it did not work.

```
noweave -filter l2h -html -delay -n -index src.nw > src.html
```

Instead the html file showed "ill-understood graphics".

The image is "cases.png" in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the noweb distributed by the OS is built to use AWK. I downloaded the noweb and built it using icon. Now the html page shows the correct image.